# Generate pdf in django

Tags: python, django, pdf

I'm making a web store and need to generate a pdf with orders. I've looked for, but it did not clarify what would be the best option to generate that.

Any advice of what library to generate pdf from html?

Comment: [Outputting PDFs with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) works pretty well. However, it does not support 100% CSS.

You can find a working combo of HTML and CSS after little work, note that you should use tables for layout.

Answer (score 3):

I have experience with pisa http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa it works well for creating pdf from html. If you're using paver just add to your requirements.txt:
pisa
reportlab
html5lib

Answer (score 1):

ReportLab is a good solution to your problem.

http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/rl-toolkit/download/

```
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed two options, they might be helpful:

The first one is official Django docs itself, here is the link
       https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/

Second one is from google code ( Django-report) please have a look, here is the link.
       http://code.google.com/p/django-report/